# Couldn't set cookie with flask

Tags: python, vue.js, cookies, flask, session-cookies

For development I am using vuejs which is being served by webpack at my local address: `172.18.0.77:8080` and flask that is run by Werkzeug at address `172.18.0.77:5000`. I am trying to set cookie to some `GET` request by running this code:

```
response_data = Response(json.dumps(some_json_data, indent=True), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
response_data.set_cookie('user_session_id', value='12345', domain='172.18.0.77:8080')
return response_data
```

But when I am trying to read this cookie with following code `request.cookies.get('user_session_id')` I am receiving only `None` value.

I also tried to set cookie by changing domain to `172.18.0.77` like:

```
 response_data.set_cookie('user_session_id', value='12345', domain='172.18.0.77')
```

But it also doesn't work

Comment: @asergio Thanks for response! I just have tried to migrate to local domains using hosts file and set cookies with this code `response_data.set_cookie('user_session_id', value='12345', domain='domain.local:8080')` and just `response_data.set_cookie('user_session_id', value='12345', domain='domain.local')` but flask still could't read this cookies. By the way, as it was with just ip's I can see coolies in headers.

Answer (score 1):

if you use axios in vuejs, i suggest that you can add `withCredentials: true`

```
const instance = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    ....
})
```

And in flask

```
@app.after_request
def handle_credentials(response):
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = True
    return response
```